# Solve this cipher puzzle

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

`PJb6bN5lUW3R0ZbRrfWMf4swe6CZyqBPS4GT8+bzoLE=`

This is a cipher that cannot figure out. It's probably a url but it doesn't look like one. I'm thinking its a math problem or something?

Comment: Can you give context please. Where did you find this?

Comment: Looks like [base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Decoding it gives `<leQm 0{OK`. Not sure what that means.

Comment: From a simple search online it appears that this code is from the "Im Poppy" girl on youtube. Even although it is mysterious you should reference the original source, it is a standard on this exchange

Comment: welcome to PSE! sorry but this doesn't seem on-topic here, for the uses of this website, feel free to look up at the help centre. posting irrelevant questions here may result in receiving downvotes and having the question closed. for this question, maybe [https://crypto.stackexchange.com/] can help?

Answer (score 5):

As a coder as well, this is definitely a Base64 encoded string. From your original: `PJb6bN5lUW3R0ZbRrfWMf4swe6CZyqBPS4GT8+bzoLE=`, see as follows:

Unfortunately, this string is probably not the entire source.

However, [one decoder](https://codebeautify.org/base64-decode) output this particular string. Oddly enough, this particular string is largely in Chinese:

> <溬ޥQmё摭匿밻يϋᓳ泠က

Problem with the above output is that it is mixed with code, so it is probably a fluke, and the original Base64 string is probably really a portion of html code. Anyhow, let's proceed as if this were the cipher, since it is what is directly output from it.

First of all, the last square is caused by an error in unicode format meaning the page cannot read that particular unicode format. At least, not in my current version of Chrome browser.

Fortunately, a unicode character search still can translate the letter to a readable format. Thus, behind this square is actually the unicode character [Myanmar Letter Ka](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=%E1%80%80&preview=entity). Myanmar is the language of Burmese. "ka" can mean "to block".

The transliteration of the above Chinese characters is as follows:

> < Qiāng ޥ Qmë zhí nìbaelbyüᓳ líng ka

Chinese to English translation would make part of the above code:

Qiāng = "strong" (among other potential meanings)
[líng](https://dictionary.hantrainerpro.com/chinese-english/translation-ling_zero.htm) = "zero"
[zhí nìbaelbyüᓳ (摭匿)](http://www.systranet.com/translate/) = "picks up to conceal"

> < Strong ޥ Qmё picks up to conceal zero [to block]

ޥ is the Maldivian letter [Thaana Letter Waavu](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+07A5#UNC_DB)

Therefore we now have:

> < Strong thaana Qmё picks up to conceal zero [to block]

For `thaana`, while I don't have a direct translation it may be derived from `thana`, which means police station. However, since across languages words may be similar but change slightly in meaning, we could consider it to mean "enforce".
Let's work on the rest:

> < Strong enforce Qmё picks up to conceal zero [to block]

This leaves us with two more. `<` and `Qmё`.

`<` can mean "less than".

Unfortunately, `Qmё` is untranslatable. A google search discovers several pages with this `Qmё` in between some Chinese code. Therefore, it is probably a browser base translation issue with regards to Chinese characters. Therefore, it can probably be left out safely as it may have no human meaning, only a meaning to computers.

Therefore, our end result is as follows:

> [Less than] strong enforce picks up to conceal zero [to block]

Finally, considering that direct translations sometimes are worded oddly, let's convert this into an English sentence that makes sense:

Let's make `less-than-strong` to mean `minimal`, one possible grammatical way of more properly saying the same. Add in some implied words like "there is" and "from you" (implications often left out in eastern languages).

This brings us to the following, formatting for the best possible grammar:

> There is a minimal enforcement which is used to conceal and block nothing from you.

So there you have it! It seems that nothing is in that code after all, for that's exactly what it says.

Comment: I think this solution would exactly fit Poppy's profile